# thread and event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)
>   [WPF access GUI from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363920/wpf-access-gui-from-other-thread)

Good day , 
I write class

```
 public class Metric1
 {
        public event MetricUnitEventHandler OnUnitRead;


       public void ReiseEventOnUnitRead(string MetricUnitKey)
       {
            if (OnUnitRead!=null)
             OnUnitRead(this,new MetricUnitEventArgs(MetricUnitKey));
        }   
 .....
 }    

 Metric1 m1 = new Metric1();
 m1.OnUnitRead += new MetricUnitEventHandler(m1_OnUnitRead);

 void m1_OnUnitRead(object sender, MetricUnitEventArgs e)
 {
        MetricUnits.Add(((Metric1)sender));
        lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = null;
        lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = MetricUnits;    
 }
```

Then i start new thread that every  minute calls m1's ReiseEventOnUnitRead method.

In row   `lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = null`;  throws excepition - **"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."**  Why?

Comment: This has been asked & answered many times. Here's a [List](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf+%22other+thread%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Dispatcher.
Example:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => {  
        lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = null;
        lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = MetricUnits;    
})));
```

In WPF and Forms -> you cannot modify UI controls from different thread.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change GUI item from another thread that isn't the GUI thread,

If you are working with WinForms use Invoke and InvokeRequired.

```
if (lstMetricUnit.InvokeRequired)
{        
    // Execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns
    // 'lstMetricUnit' control's underlying window handle.
    lstMetricUnit.Invoke(lstMetricUnit.myDelegate);        
}
else
{
    lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = null;
    lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = MetricUnits;
}
```

If you are working with WPF use Dispatcher.

```
lstMetricUnit.Dispatcher.Invoke(
          System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          new Action(
            delegate()
            {
              lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = null;
              lstMetricUnit.ItemsSource = MetricUnits;   
            }
        ));
```